# Are you required to call the a super class's implementation from each and every subclass's function

Tags: swift, functional-programming, subclass, superclass

e.g. you have a subclass defined which overrides a function f in its superclass. Inside the override, are you required to call the superclass's f function.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The OP is not asking about initializers.

Comment: ...and Swift is not Objective-C!

Comment: No. If you had to invoke a subclasses specific implementation of a method *and* the superclass's generic implementation, OOP wouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is false, you don't need to call the superclass method you are overriding in Swift or in OOP in general. That would be a horrible limitation if you did! There are times when you should in fact not call it and perhaps the most common example is when you create a `UIViewController` programmatically and have to override `loadView()` *without* calling `super.loadView()`.

Comment: `super.loadView()`  is called for loading IB layout in adition to the added content inside it

Comment: He asked if you are required to call the superclass method when you override it. No, you are not required. Every programmatically-created view controller overrides a superclass method without calling super.

Comment: @bsod Most programatically-created view controller call `super` everywhere because they override `viewDidLoad` and not `loadView`. `UIViewController.loadView` should be overridden only in very special circumstances.

Comment: @Sulthan A programmatically-created view controller must create its own view in `loadView` and must never call `super.loadView`. There is no such thing as a programmatically-created view controller that does not create its view in `loadView`.

Comment: @bsod All controllers, be it programmatically created or loaded behave the same. Of course all of them use `loadView` to assign `UIViewController.view`, however, you have to override that method with a custom implementation only in very special cases. For example, `UITableViewController` does that. I am saying that 99.9% of all controllers use the default implementation of `UIViewController.loadView`. I think that in many years programming iOS I never needed to override that method.

Comment: No they don't. View controllers through the storyboard are given a default `loadView` implementation by UIKit--UIKit instantiates the subviews, connects the outlets, and assigns the root view to the view controller's `view` property. That is why you must call `super.loadView()` for non-programmatic view controllers. A programmatic view controller has no default `loadView()`, it's empty, and that's why you don't call `super.loadView()`. There is no such thing as a programmatic view controller that doesn't declare `view = UIView()` inside `loadView()`. Your view controllers aren't programmatic.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is not really related to Swift but it's related to all OOP languages.

The simple answer is: No, you are *not required* to call the superclass implementation.

Whether you should call the superclass implementation or not should be stated in the documentation. When you are not sure, you should generally always call the super implementation.

You have to consider the fact that the superclass does something inside the method and if you don't call the superclass implementation, the subclass doesn't have to work properly.

Not calling the superclass implementation means that you want to prevent the superclass implementation from happening and that usually means your whole inheritance model is flawed.

One notable exception is the situation when the superclass provides some default implementation which you want to replace inside your subclass (e.g. `UIViewController.loadView`). That's not a very common use case though.

There are also other obvious exceptions, for example getters. When you are overriding a getter to return a custom object, there is usually no need to call `super`. However, again, even getters can technically initialize some structures in the superclass and it might be needed to call super.

Answer (score 1):

The default is that you call `super`, **unless** you know you're not breaking that function.

---

I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/prohoney/55479733b2670661884dc5aa6e1ffbc2). You can copy it to your own playground and play around with it. But the answer is:

I had this exact confusion of yours. You're basically asking what's the difference between **extending** behavior vs. **overriding** behavior.

Swift doesn't do a good a job of telling your their difference. 
What they both share is that both need to mark the function with `override`, but sometimes you're doing something in addition to the superclass's implementation (extending), and sometimes you're just completely rewriting it (overriding)

Suppose we have the following class:

```
class Person {

    var age : Int?

    func incrementAge() {
        guard age != nil else {
            age = 1
            return
        }
        age! += 1
    }

    func eat() {
        print("eat popcorn")
    }
}
```

We can just initialize it and do:

```
var p1 = Person()
p1.incrementAge() // works fine
```

Now suppose we did this:

```
class Boy : Person{

    override func incrementAge() {
        age! += 2
    }
}

var b1 = Boy()
b1.incrementAge()
```

What do you think is going to happen?!

**It will crash.** Because in the super class, we're doing a `nil` check for `age`, but in our subclass we never call `super`

To make it work we have to call `super`.

```
class GoodBoy : Person{

    override func incrementAge() {
        super.incrementAge()
        age! += 2
    }
}

var b2 = GoodBoy()
b2.incrementAge() // works fine.
```

We could get away without calling `super` directly.

```
class AlternateGoodBoy : Person{

    override func incrementAge() {
        guard age != nil else {
            age = 1
            return
        }
        age! += 2
    }
}

var b3 = AlternateGoodBoy()
b3.incrementAge() // works fine.
```

^^ The above works, yet the superclass's implementation is not always known to us. A real example is `UIKit`. We don't know what happens really when `viewDidLoad` is called. Hence we must call `super.viewDidLoad`

---

That being said sometimes we could just not call `super` and be totally fine because we know what super does or maybe just don't care and want to completely get rid of it. e.g. :

```
class Girl : Person{
    override func eat() {
        print("eat hotdog")
    }
}

var g1 = Girl()
g1.eat() // doesn't crash, even though you overrode the behavior. It doesn't crash because the call to super ISN'T critical
```

Yet the most common case is that you call `super`, but also add something on top of it.

```
class Dad : Person {
    var moneyInBank = 0
    override func incrementAge() {
        super.incrementAge()
        addMoneyToRetirementFunds()
    }

    func addMoneyToRetirementFunds() {
        moneyInBank += 2000
    }
}

var d1 = Dad()
d1.incrementAge()
print(d1.moneyInBank) // 2000
```

---

**Pro tip:**

Unlike most overrides where you first call `super` then the rest, for a `tearDown` function, it’s best to call `super.tearDown()` at the end of the function. In general, for any 'removal' functions, you'd want to call super at the end. e.g. `viewWillDisAppear`/`viewDidDisappear`